# CSS based on viewport height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Goldman Sachs has a pretty cool webpage [here](http://www.goldmansachs.com/our-thinking/pages/millennials/). What interests me about the page is that when you scroll down, you get a header appearing, which - depending on the section where you're at - has more of its squares turn from white to blue. I was wondering (because I can't seem to find the answer in the code), how exactly they made the scrollbar appear seemingly out of the blue (pun not intended), but also how the squares turn from white to blue depending on where you are on the page.

Comment: They measure the position of the page when scrolling then show the header when it reaches a certain point, then add/change classes on elements to give the effects you see within the header (or they might use javascript, don't have time to look) when other scroll points are reached - simple stuff, loads of resources out there to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most common way to do this is by detecting the position of the scrollbar with javascript. I've used the JQuery library for this demo.

here's some code (merely for illustration purpose!)

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var numOfButtons = 4;
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     var heightContainer =      $(".container").height();
  console.log('scrollPos', scroll);
   
  if(scroll > heightContainer/ numOfButtons){
    $(".header .button:nth-child(2)").addClass('act');
  }else{
    $(".header .button:nth-child(2)").removeClass('act');
  }
  
  if(scroll > (heightContainer/ numOfButtons)*2){
    $(".header .button:nth-child(3)").addClass('act');
  }else{
    $(".header .button:nth-child(3)").removeClass('act');
  }
                 
  if(scroll > (heightContainer/ numOfButtons)*3){
    $(".header .button:nth-child(4)").addClass('act');
  }else{
    $(".header .button:nth-child(4)").removeClass('act');
  }    
                 
   
});
```

```css
.header{
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%
  
}
.button{
  display:inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius:20px;
}
.button.act{
  background-color:red;
}
h1{
  margin-top:60px;
}
.container{
  height:4000px;
  background:url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/518164-backgrounds.jpg");
}
```

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <h1>Scroll demo</h1>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="button act"></div>
      <div class="button"></div>
      <div class="button"></div>
      <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container"><div id="mydiv"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/johandegrieck/pen/EPOVMJ?editors=0101)

Answer (score 1):

you can easily achieve an effect like that using jquery waypoints: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

the first thing that comes to my mind is adding a class with `display:block` to the header when a certain section hits the top of the viewport to make it visible and playing with `addClass` and `removeClass` with css transitions for the squares.